# Ajax is not updating data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a forum in which user is allowed to edit and delete only his comments, I've defined an "edit" button, that by a click of mouse brings down a modal, and in that modal user is allowed to get access to the data's he/she has been sent before, I've written an ajax to target these field and update them whenever the users clicks on "edit" button, code totally makes sense, but so far the functionality doesn't, to make it more clear, user clicks, modal comes down, whatever he/she has been posted will appear in fields, and there is an "edit" button at the bottom of modal, which is responsible for changing and updating data. here is the modal code :

```
                <button id="btn-btnedit"   class="btn btn-primary " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $list['id']; ?>">
                  Edit <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                </button>


                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $list['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="container">
                                    <form style="width: 550px;" action="" method="post" id="signin-form<?php echo $list['id']; ?>" role="form">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="commentID" value="<?php echo $list['id']; ?>">
                                    <div class="from-group">

                                        <label for="title">Title: </label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" id="txttitle" value="<?php echo $list['title']; ?>" placeholder="Page Title">

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="from-group">

                                        <label for="label">Label: </label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="label" id="txtlabel" value="<?php echo $list['label']; ?>" placeholder="Page Label">

                                    </div>

                                    <br>

                                     <div class="from-group">

                                        <label for="body">Body: </label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control editor" name="body" id="txtbody" row="8" placeholder="Page Body"><?php echo $list['body']; ?></textarea>

                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="editted" value="1">
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="submit" id="btnupdate" value="Edit">
                                </form>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

as you can see I've assigned "editted" to my "name" attribute, which is later on used to call the query in the database, sql code is as below :

```
        case 'postupdate';

        if(isset($_GET['editted'])){

                $title = $_GET['title'];
                $label = $_GET['label'];
                $body = $_GET['body'];

                    $action = 'Updated';
                    $q = "UPDATE posts SET title ='".$title."', label = '".$label."', body = '".$body."' WHERE id = ".$_GET['commentID'];
                    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);


                    $message = '<p class="alert alert-success"> Your Post Is Succesfully '.$action.'</p>' ; 


            }
```

and here is the ajax code snippet;

```
    $('#btnupdate').click(function() {
    var tempTitle = $('#txttitle').val();
    var tempLabel = $('#txtlabel').val();
    var tempBody = $('#txtbody').val();
    var tempUrl = "index.php?page=postupdate"+"&title="+tempTitle+"&label="+tempLabel+"&body="+tempBody+"&commentID=30&editted=1";
    $.get(tempUrl);
});
```

I assume there is nothing advance about this segment of code, and i'm missing something very simple, any consideration is highly appreciated :)

Comment: You should do a post instead of a get. Content might be to long. Also it's not really safe what you're doing (sql injections)

Comment: Hello Daan, Tried it before posting this, Well, it's something more than the method I suppose

Comment: You don't do anything with the result of the .get() you are not passing a callback...

Comment: Also when you submit you should do a `preventDefault()`

Comment: `$.get(tempUrl,somedata,function(data) {alert('received: '+data);});`

Comment: Use mysqli_prepare and then mysqli_stmt_execute in the place of mysqli_query. 
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->_dbHandle,$query);
$result= mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

Comment: Yes I agree with @vinod, your PHP script is very vulnerable to attacks, use prepare and execute!!

Comment: Well, Functionality first, then we will get to security, @jonathan Lenowski, do you have any idea how should I code it ?

Comment: @EscapeCharacter - did you checked the console for the error? If there is no error and ajax sending data to case 'postupdate'; then your update command  not working. Please verify ajax sending data or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (untested code) may be similar to what you should do:

```
$('#btnupdate').click(function() {
    var tempTitle = $('#txttitle').val();
    var tempLabel = $('#txtlabel').val();
    var tempBody = $('#txtbody').val();
    var tempParams = {"page":"postupdate","title":tempTitle,"label":tempLabel,"body":tempBody,"commentID":30,"editted":1};

    $.post("index.php",tempParams,function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Try ajax instead of get to see if some error occurs in the loading

```
$.ajax( {url:"index.php",data:tempParams,type: "POST"} ).done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
}).fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
}).always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
});`
```

**UPDATE**

Start testing if the click handler works then (just to be sure!):

$('#btnupdate').click(function() { alert("yes at least the button was pressed"); });

**UPDATE**

Start testing if the script gets executed then:

```
alert("yes at least the script gets executed");
$('#btnupdate').click(function() { alert("yes at least the button was pressed"); });
```

If not you must have a javascript error somewhere.
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

If yes, your button does not get caught by JQuery (no idea why)

anyway it's got nothing to do with ajax or get!

Comment: @EscapeCharacter no javascript error, no loading, no action?

Comment: there is a loading, I don't know what for, but no error, no action so far..... I've tried to update the data manually through URL it worked, but somehow in this piece of codes, something is missing, and i'm terribly looking for it ....

Comment: @EscapeCharacter maybe try $.ajax instead so you can also add a failure handler: `var jqxhr = $.ajax( {url:"index.php",data:tempParams} )
.done(function() {
alert( "success" );
})
.fail(function() {
alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
alert( "complete" );
});`